# How to have radio buttons with Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button

In my search form, I want to make the choice of categories available with the selection of one of them, and only one of them. For now I have checkboxes instead of having radio buttons.

How do I get radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

SearchType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Categories;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bigcity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => BigCity::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionne une grande ville'
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Categories::class,
                'choice_label' => 'image',
                'expanded' => 'true',
                'multiple' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For radio buttons use

```php
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Categories::class,
                'choice_label' => 'image',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
            ])
```

Also - be sure to use actual values (`true` not `'true'` - a string)!

[Doc is here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons)

Comment: Thanks craigh. You're probably right, but it hasn't changed... I'm updating my code in the description so that maybe someone will find the error somewhere else... Thank you.

Comment: Note for next answerer : I tested with 'expanded' => 'false', but I didn't get select tag as I was supposed to.

Comment: @EmilieTossan are you in dev mode? If not, you will need to delete your cache _every time_ you make a change.

Comment: Hi craigh. I have APP_ENV=dev written in my .env.local file. I believe it means I am in dev mode. However, I delete my cache very often... I'll keep doing it, but it seems it doesn't change any thing... at all.

Comment: Symfony version?

Comment: 6.0.2. (Sorry I have to write a sentence, number of characters is not enough.)

Comment: Actually, it worked. I just deleted 'multiple' => 'false'. And it seems, it doesn't take into account 'expanded', whether it's 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: In any case, I validate your solution. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Ah! I figured out the problem with my answer (and probably yours). You were using _strings_ (e.g. `'true'` not '`true`) and so, they were interpreted as "truthy". I adjusted my answer to use actual `true` and `false` (not strings). I suspect if you try the actual values it will work as you should expect.

Comment: Yes, that worked very well. ^^